# Having an issue with selecting max rows by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select the max timestamped records from table 1 based on some data from table 2. I am getting the correct records based on the where limits I have put on the query, but I am still getting duplicate entries not the max time stamped entries. Any ideas on what is wrong with the query?

Basically the ID 901413368 has access to certain leveltypes and I'm trying to find out what the max dated requests were that were put in for that same person for the leveltypes that person manages.

```
SELECT  
MAX(timestamp) AS maxtime, Leveltype, assign_ID
FROM       
WHERE 
(leveltype IN
(SELECT leveltype FROM  dbo.idleveltypes  WHERE   (id = 901413368)))
GROUP BY timestamp, assign_ID, leveltype
HAVING   (assign_ID = '901413368')
```

UPDATE: The issue has been resolved by  WEI_DBA's response below:

```
Remove the timestamp column from your Group By. Also put the assign_ID in     the Where Clause and remove the Having clause
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you want to do (better than a non-working query, in fact).

Comment: Can you please add expected result and actual result and server version as well

Comment: Remove the `timestamp` column from your Group By. Also put the `assign_ID` in the Where Clause and remove the Having clause.

Comment: Thanks WEI_DBA. Setting it up like you mentioned works perfectly. Also thanks to everyone else for helping out. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

The following may be what you want.  It should also be a simpler way to write the query:

```
SELECT MAX(a.timestamp) AS maxtime, a.Leveltype, a.assign_ID
FROM dbo.q_Archive a JOIN
     dbo.idleveltypes lt
     ON a.leveltype = lt.leveltype AND
        a.assign_ID = lt.id
WHERE assign_ID = 901413368
GROUP BY assign_ID, leveltype;
```

Notes:

- Filter on `assign_ID` *before* doing the `group by`.  That is much more efficient.
- A `JOIN` is the more typical way to represent the relationship between two tables.
- The `JOIN` condition should be on all the columns needed for matching; there appear to be two.
- I don't understand why the `leveltype` table would have a column called `id`, but this is your data structure.
- The `GROUP BY` does not need `timestamp`.
- Decide on the type for the id column that should be `901413368`.  Is it a number or a string?  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Answer (score 1):

Remove timestamp from GROUP BY clause due you're getting MAX(timestamp)

You shoud not add aggregated fields to GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT        
    MAX(timestamp) AS maxtime, 
    Leveltype, 
    assign_ID
FROM
    dbo.q_Archive
WHERE
    (leveltype IN (SELECT        leveltype
                           FROM            dbo.idleveltypes
                           WHERE        (id = 901413368)))
GROUP assign_ID, leveltype
HAVING        (assign_ID = '901413368')
```